# OpenGL ES 2.0 rendering issue in Xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm fairly new to OpenGL ES 2.0 on the iPhone and am trying to make a simple animation of bumper cars in a ring. For some reason, I am currently unable to render anything on screen (only the glClear() set color shows up rather any 3D objects) and I think it has something to do with my base effect or possibly my binding/rendering. I'm currently unsure of what the issue is and have been stumped for quite some time now. Would anyone be able to take a look through my project and try to guide me? I just need a footing for the right direction in debugging this issue. Just click the attached link and go to File -> Download to get the entire project.

Edit: I did find an issue under SceneMesh.h where SceneMeshVertex had  GLKVector2 texCoords0; declared as  GLKVector3 texCoords0; which is wrong. So that has been corrected and updated.

[Xcode Project](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_1MmjVEMIQnTDd4dDJHaXdaR2M/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

In SceneModel.m I made a goof. In 
-(id)initWithName:(NSString *)modelName mesh:(SceneMesh *)meshReference numberOfVertices:(GLsizei)count; I accidentally reference numberOfVertices instead of count .... woops. That fixed that.